# Ubuntu 18.04 does not recognize users after bios (UEFI) update

Tags: authentication

I have updated from 17.10 to 18.04 successfully.  I flashed my BIOS to a newer version.  Now, when I go to enter my password, I am not recognized. Can this be fixed?  ASUS TP300LD laptop i5 processor, 8Gigs ram.

Comment: It's a common bug where it tells you the first time your password is invalid (even though you type it correct) and you have to enter it a second time. Your problem might be different though...

Comment: It actually never gives a message invalid password, it just recycles back to the login screen.

Comment: OK that's a new bug to me.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. Turns out when I flashed the bios, secure boot was set to enabled.  Disabled I can login.

Comment: Resetting UEFI (or BIOS) generally resets system to defaults. With UEFI some settings may be saved, but others are not.